# how to resolve Firebase projects adding quota problem?

Tags: android, firebase, quota

I was facing a problem exceeding adding projects limit quota that time i had more than 5 projects. then I deleted some projects but still i am getting the same error. can it be resolved by deleting projects or not?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for questions regarding the administration of your account and projects.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: ok, thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete a project it is actually "pending deletion", so that you can potentially recover it. Only 30 days after you mark the project for deletion, is the project actually deleted.